# Dirac delta and initial conditions of a linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

Suppose that you want to solve the following linear, time-invariant, non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation of order $N$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^{(n)}(t) =k \delta(t),$$

where $a_n \in \mathbb{R}~\forall n$, $a_N \neq 0$, $x^{(n)}(t)$ is the $n-th$ derivative of $x(t)$ ($x^{(0)}(t) = x(t)$), $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta. 
Suppose also that initial conditions are $x(0) = x^{(1)}(0) = \ldots = x^{(N-1)}(0) = 0.$

**I am aware that the problem can be easily solved using the Laplace transform.**

Anyway, after a lot of ODEs solved, I realized (???) that the problem can be stated in a different way, leading to the same solution. My claim is that we can express the problem as an homogeneous one:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^{(n)}(t) =0,$$

and the initial conditions $x^{(0)}$, $x^{(1)}$, $\ldots x^{(N-1)}$ depend on $k$.

Is this true? If so, how can we formalize this?

Comment: (basically) yes, you want $x(t)$ which is a solution of the homogeneous ODE both for $t<0$ and for $t>0$, AND having the jump $k/a_n$ in the $(n-1)$st derivative (the lower derivatives are continuous). To find it you can take $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and for $t>0$ the solution of the homogeneous ODE with $x^{(i)}(0)=0$ ($i<n-1$), $x^{(n-1)}(0)=k/a_n$. As for "theory" it is just about how to compute the distributional derivative of a function with a jump - the jump produces a multiple of $\delta$.

Comment: are you sure of $x^{(N-1)} = 0 = \frac{k}{a_N}$??

Comment: The left $N-1$-st derivative is $0$, the right one is $k/a_N$.